# how to change input type date from 2017-09-13 to 2017/Sep/13?

Tags: php, html

> how to change input type date from 2017-09-13 to 2017/Sep/13 ??

```
  <input type="date" name="ddat" format="YYYY-MM-DD" >
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = $_POST['date'];
$date = date("Y/M/d", strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the date form any format to any other format by using `date()` like:

```
$newDate = date('Y/M/d', strtotime($oldDate));

echo $newDate ;  // 2017/Sep/13
```

[Php Fiddle link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d42652fd233b3d8ae7953cf5b3d2c97a855c6501)